# What is difference between Test Design & Test Architecture?

Tags: test-design, interview, test-architecture

Could anyone explain the difference between Test Design and Test Architecture?

More specifically; if you tell someone to present **Test Design** - what would you expect them to present? Same goes for **Test Architecture**.

As per my understanding:

**Test Design**: Basically test design (HLD & LLD) is the act of creating and writing test suites for testing a software.

**Test Architecture**: test component diagram (showing how the different modules of the system communicate with each other and other systems), what language is to be used, patterns...

Comment: What did you learned from googling?

Comment: I couldn't get much specific information ...I mention my current understanding in the question based on my research .

Comment: You can also do some reading on software engineering SE. Basically, architecture is high(er)-level design.

Comment: Actually I gone through some SE books or blogs but no one discussed difference directly it's looking pretty much same or on what basis we can decide degree or level (high or low)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of many definitions, taken from the [ISTQB glossary (v3.1)](http://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/20-istqb-glossary/186-glossary-all-terms.html):

> **test architect**
>
> (1) A person who provides guidance and strategic direction for a test organization and for its relationship with other disciplines. (2) A person who defines the way testing is structured for a given system, including topics such as test tools and test data management.
>
> **test design**
>
> The process of transforming general test objectives into tangible test conditions and test cases.

Essentially, *test design* boils down to designing test cases and test suites, whereas *test architecture* is about the bigger picture (tools, data, process, strategy, compliance, etc.).